# How can i fix the bad substitution?

Tags: bash, shell

I got loc_list0,1,2,3,
and i try to do it efficiently and type

```
b=0
while [ $b -lt 4 ]
do
     grep -c "${loc_list$b[0]}" Record$b.txt
done
```

It says Bad Substitution on ${loc_list$b[0]}, but ok for Record$b. What is the reason behind? I am new to bash shell can anyone tell me how to fix it instead of writing duplicate codes.

Thanks man!
But another problems come when i want to use two varibales for iteration
thanks man, how about i got two variables
b and c which works as counting numbers of iteration
such that:

```
b=0
c=0
while [ $b -lt 5 ]
do
    temp_length=( "${loc_list$b[@]}" )
    while [ $c -lt ${#temp_length[@]} ]
    do
       ...
       c=$((c+1))
    done
 ...
b=$((b+1))
done
```

how to fix the bad substitution this time?

Comment: You've got an infinite loop. Don't forget to increment `b`

Comment: The `${loc_list$b[0]}` is evaluated once and returns a string that looks like a variable. A dangerous solution would be using `eval`, you should choose between using arrays, or use similar lines for the different vars. When you have a lot code that you don't want to duplicate, make a function and call that function for all your var's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use indirect parameter substitution. With arrays, the index you want is considered part of the name.

```
name=loc_list$b[0]
grep -c "${!name}" Record$b.txt
```

`Record$b.txt` works because it is a simple string concatenation, `Record` + `$b` + `.txt`. You aren't try to further expand the result.